# Is it possible to connect multiple couchbase clusters using spring-data-couchbase?

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I have a scenario where I need to connect to two buckets. Each bucket is in a different couchbase cluster. Is it possible to configure with two buckets which are in two different clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* be possible to define an additional `Cluster` bean, associated `Bucket` bean and `CouchbaseTemplate`. It is certainly possible with 2 buckets within the same cluster, so you could start from there: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.multibucket